# Convert Java Array to Scala WrappedArray (In JAVA)

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm writing a Java Spark application and I'm trying to write a unit test for one of my UDFs. This UDF accept Array of String and return Long:

```
protected UDF1<WrappedArray<String>, Long> convertMyArray() {
    return (WrappedArray<String> s) -> {
        
        return ...;
    };
}
```

When I test it with a Spark session, the logic works fine. my problem is how can I `unittest` this logic.

```
 @Test
    public void arrayConversion() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> inputName = new ArrayList<String>() {
            {
                add("Inp1");
                add("Inp2");
            }
        };

        assertEquals(5, myUDF.convertMyArray().call(...);
        
    }
```

How can I convert `inputName` into wappedArray. I can not just simply pass `inputName` into my UDF call because of input mismatch.

I have also tried to use `make` based on [WrappedArray.scala::Make](https://github.com/scala/legacy-svn-scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.scala#L90)

```
WrappedArray<String> stringInput = WrappedArray.make(inputName);
```

But I still get run time error:

```
scala.MatchError: [Inp1, Inp2] when using make
```

Comment: The companion object in [WrappedArray.scala](https://github.com/scala/legacy-svn-scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.scala#L90) has a `make` method. Is that method showing up in your setup?

Comment: @aksappy I am getting scala.MatchError: [Inp1, Inp2] when using make

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are constructing a Java `ArrayList`, which isn't an array but a Java collection.

You can convert it to a `WrappedArray` with

```java
WrappedArray<String> stringInput = WrappedArray.make(inputName.toArray(new String[0]))
```